# How to create a C# enumerable of generic with multiple types?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have an interface `IThingy` that exposes a set of shared properties:

```
public interface IThingy<T>
{
    public string Name { get; init; }
    public int Priority { get; init; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

This is implemented by a number of classes, e.g.:

```
public class TextThingy : IThingy<string?>
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = "A Text Thingy"
    public int Priority { get; init; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}

public class NumberThingy: IThingy<int?>
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = "A Number Thingy"
    public int Priority { get; init; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

Another class keeps a collection of thingies, that I want to enumerate over and use to generate JSON for an API.

```
public class ThingyGroup 
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = "A Group of Related Thingies";
    public IEnumerable<IThingy<???>> Thingies { get; init; } = new List<IThingy<???>>();
}
```

What can I use there so that this list can accept multiple different kinds of Thingies?

Leaving it without a type parameter means ThingyGroup gives me an error about Thingies needing a type argument.

Setting the type parameter to object and dynamic gave me errors when trying to add a TextThingy or NumberThingy to the list.

Comment: It seems like structs might be good for this if you mean multiple things at once. Otherwise, object oriented programming saves the day with multiple classes that inherit, however this is builtin to most json libraries that I know of with JsonValue having multiple possible types.

Comment: Side note: consider moving to newer versions of C# (6 came with VS 2015...)

Comment: Why a `ThingyGroup` must contain different types, couldn't it be a `NumberThingyGroup`, for example? If not, maybe it's a good use-case for `dynamic`, so a `IEnumerable<IThingy<dynamic>>`, especially because you use json which can handle `dynamic`. We often use `dynamic` in our API's to fill request payloads.

Comment: ThingyGroup is a DTO that should hold all kinds of IThingy for serialization to JSON. Having a specific ThingyGroup for each kind of Thingy (even using generics) will break the contract of what I want to output from my API.